# Как сделать управление персонажем в браузерной онлайн игре?

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр

я пытаюсь сделать онлайн игру. могу сделать вход и регистрацию, но дальше застреваю: не могу понять как сделать управление персонажем.

мне нужно, чтобы персонаж с помощью стрелок на клавиатуре ходил вправо, влево, вверх и вниз.

сначала его надо вывести на экран, а потом?.. подскажите, пожалуйста?

Comment: А потом, по событиям нажатия кнопок менять его позицию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй сверстать блок на html, у которого с помощью css будет меняться позиционирование относительно родительского элемента. Значения css (которые будут отвечать за позиционирование этого блока/элемента/объекта) - получаешь через переменные JavaScript. Вешаешь события-обработчики на кнопки-стрелки, где обработчики будут получать текущие значения переменных и изменять их. Потом меняешь внешний вид "блока/элемента/объекта" на изображения персонажа. Обработчик событий нажатия кнопок-стрелок так же может менять изображение персонажа в зависимости от направления стрелки/движения.

Comment: Много игроков за одной клавиатурой?